# DNN Module TSQL order

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dotnetnuke

To preface: I am producing a dnn module(A) with a dependency on a released module(B) and should not modify the other module(B).

I having a problem with retreiving information from an SQL table that should be modified by the module B. Module B may delete a row on page_load, but I need to generate controls based on the info in the SQL table.

I have tried WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:xx'; to precede my SQL commands in module A, but unfortunately, it merely prolongs page_load and delete on module(B) occurs during/after page_load.

I contemplated using the unload event, but controls can not be added after the page is rendered.

Currently I am redirecting twice for every postback, but this seems hacky, and I would like to implement a smoother solution if possible.

Again, the modules have to be on the same page, and I cannot modify Module B.

Comment: Could you just create a web service that Module A calls via javascript after the page loads fully and retrieve the data then?

Comment: this is exactly what I need to do, thanks for the tip (and all of your tutorials)